# Bundling opencv as a static library gives thousands of undefined references

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, cmake

I have a library that I am trying to link with openCV (and I think I did successfully) into one big dynamic library. I then try and add an executable and link everything together to test the library and I get 2000-3000 errors each saying

```
In function `________________`: undefined reference to `________`
```

some examples are:

```
/path/to/libs/libopencv_features2d.a(matchers.cpp.o): In function `cv::FlannBasedMatcher::read(cv::FileNode const&)':
matchers.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17FlannBasedMatcher4readERKNS_8FileNodeE+0x227): undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::setAlgorithm(int)'

/path/to/libs/libopencv_videoio.a(cap_gstreamer.cpp.o)` In function `CvCapture_GStreamer::getProperty(int) const':
cap_gstreamer.cpp:(.text._ZNK19CvCapture_GStreamer11getPropertyEi+0x8b): undefined reference to `gst_element_query_position'

/path/to/lib/libopencv_core.a(stat.cpp.o): In function `cv::norm(cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::_InputArray const&)':
stat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4normERKNS_11_InputArrayEiS2_+0x1d27): undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_32f_C1MR'
stat.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4normERKNS_11_InputArrayEiS2_+0x1dab): undefined reference to `ippicviNorm_L1_8u_C1MR'
```

My cmake file which runs:

```
project(SDK-build)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(MYLIB_SRC
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
    file3.cpp
)

add_library(gesture SHARED ${MYLIB_SRC})

cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)
link_directories(./opencvlib-wgstreamer)
set(OPENCV_LIBS
    libopencv_calib3d.a
    libopencv_core.a
    libopencv_features2d.a
    libopencv_highgui.a
    libopencv_imgcodecs.a
    libopencv_imgproc.a
    libopencv_ml.a
    libopencv_objdetect.a
    libopencv_photo.a
    libopencv_video.a
    libopencv_videoio.a
)

set(TEST_SRC
    test.cpp
)

add_executable(gesture_test ${TEST_SRC})

#build library
#target_link_libraries(gesture -Wl,-whole-archive ${OPENCV_LIBS} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)

#build library with executable
target_link_libraries(gesture_test gesture -Wl,-whole-archive ${OPENCV_LIBS} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

When I use the first target_link_libraries, everything builds and `make` has no problem executing, but linking with the file with main() causes the massive confusion. Any suggestions I've been banging my head over this for  hours. I also tried several combinations of compiling opencv, using both `WITH_IPP=ON`, `WITH_IPP=OFF`, and `WITH_GSTREAMER_ON`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the libraries in the correct order.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) for more information.

*Edit* I see you are using -Wl-whole-archive which I believe is an other possible way to fix the problem, so maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Yes your edit is right. So far I have learned that I need to link against `-lpthread`, I have forgotten about `libopencv_flann` and I have added `-Wl,--no-as-needed` before `${OpenCV_LIBS}`